# Как сделать кнопку неактивной и сохранить её в sheredpreferences(android)

Tags: java, android, android-shared-preferences, android-button

Как сделать кнопку неактивной в sheredpreferences так как после перезахода кнопка становиться активной?
вот код на создание неактивной кнопки

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {            
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    v.setClickable(false);
                }
            });
```

Comment: сохранить ее состояние true/false в sheredpreferences

Comment: Я тоже думал, но не додумался как. так как кнопкка не может быть boolean, а по другому ни как

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавим это в onCreate

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

if(preference.getBoolean("checked", false)){
button.setEnabled(false);
}
```

далее напишем

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {            
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    button.setEnabled(false);
editor.putBoolean("checked", true);
editor.apply();
                }
            });
```

Comment: setChecked не сработает так как это кнопка

Comment: используйте setEnabled вместе setChecked!